# Intel Quartus Error 12002 Port does not exist in macrofunction

Tags: vhdl, intel, fpga, can-bus, quartus

Working with an Intel Cyclone 10 FPGA and running into a compile error I cannot seem to debug properly. The errors I get are:

```
Error (12002): Port "out_msg" does not exist in macrofunction "inst6"
Error (12002): Port "msg" does not exist in macrofunction "inst5"
Error: Quartus Prime Analysis & Synthesis was unsuccessful. 2 errors, 68 warnings
    Error: Peak virtual memory: 4803 megabytes
    Error: Processing ended: Wed Jan 06 09:42:35 2021
    Error: Elapsed time: 00:00:09
    Error: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:19
Error (293001): Quartus Prime Full Compilation was unsuccessful. 4 errors, 68 warnings
```

The two errors are of the same issue I believe.
[Here is the relevant .bdf layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9BQB.png)

Here is the code in the "inst6" block, the one that is causing the first error

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;               -- Needed for shifts
use work.can;

entity can_pack is
  port(
    clk              : in  std_ulogic;
    rst              : in  std_ulogic;
    enbl             : in  std_ulogic;
     data_in         : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     data_in1        : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     data_in2        : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     data_in3        : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     data_in4        : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     data_in5        : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     data_in6        : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     data_in7        : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     out_msg         : out work.can.message;
     ready_out       : out std_ulogic;
    tx               : inout std_ulogic);
end can_pack;

architecture syn of can_pack is

  signal ready              : std_ulogic;
  signal msg                    : work.can.message;
  
begin
  
  process(clk, rst, data_in)

  begin
      msg.id  <= x"355"; --NOTE: With ID defined to be 12 bits, please be mindfull that you don't set the ID to be >0x7FF
      msg.len <= x"8";
      msg.dat(63 downto 56) <= data_in;
      msg.dat(55 downto 48) <= data_in1;
      msg.dat(47 downto 40) <= data_in2;
      msg.dat(39 downto 32) <= data_in3;
      msg.dat(31 downto 24) <= data_in4;
      msg.dat(23 downto 16) <= data_in5;
      msg.dat(15 downto  8) <= data_in6;
      msg.dat(7  downto  0) <= data_in7;
      out_msg <= msg;

  if rst = '1' then
    ready <= '0';
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then

    --enbl is the clock rate for message broadcast
    if enbl = '0' then
        ready <= '1';
        ready_out <= '1';
    elsif enbl = '1' then   --not sure if this is the right way to do this
        ready <= '0';
        ready_out <= '0';
     end if;
   end if;
  end process;   
end syn;
```

I believe the issue has something to do with the defined type of data being set as the output. The input of inst5 takes in the same type. When I change the type of out_msg to just a std_ulogic, the code compiles without an issue.

Here is the defined record for the out_msg data type:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package can is
  type message is record
    id  : std_ulogic_vector(11 downto 0);
    len : std_ulogic_vector(3 downto 0);
    dat : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
  end record message;
end package can;

package body can is
end package body can;
```

I am pretty new to VHDL and Quartus and such, so there may be something obvious I am missing.. but any help is appreciated.

Comment: IIRC, Using custom VHDL in BDF is limited to basic types for the ports, such as integer, std_logic and std_logic_vector. Unless something has changed recently, record types are not supported.

Comment: It's highly likely that Quartus is incapable of dealing properly with objects of record types (while Xilinx Vivado has been making inroads in the last year or so). Most commercial simulation support mixed HDL models and historically translating types is proprietary and limited.

Comment: For records with elements of the same base type (here array type std_logic_vector/std_ulogic_vector) you could provide functions to translate to and from an array type with a length of 80 and the record type or provide the record elements as separate objects.

Comment: As an aside, you I believe you need to include msg in your process sensitivity list to make sure outmsg works correctly in simulation.  Or better yet, move all of the signal assignments to msg and outmsg <= msg out of the process entirely since it doesn't need to be in a process.